# Cómo identifico y muestro los números no usados de un arreglo numérico C#?

Tags: c#

Necesito mostrar los números que no se han usado. Los números van desde el 1 al 48. Este es el código que estoy finalizando:

```
bool encontre = false;

for (int i = 1; i <= 48; i++)
{
    encontre = true;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    for (int  x= 0; x < tope; x++)
    {
        encontre = false;
        for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            if (matriz[x, z] == i)
            {
                encontre = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (encontre == false)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: estoy ya lo vimos con tu compa.. no puede haber un solo encontre.. hay 48 numeros a buscar.. ve al chat ;)

Comment: Qué valor tiene asignado la variable `tope`?  Qué es la variable `matriz`? Qué valores tiene la variable `matriz`? Cómo se estructuran los datos de la `matriz`? Por favor, incluye las partes del código que ayuden a responder estas interrogantes. :D

Answer (score 0):

éste tema lleva tiempo sin contestar por falta de detalles, pero me voy a tomar la libertad de contestar la pregunta por si alguien pueda tener la misma duda imaginando una situación ficticia

Mi solución se basa en buscar los valores que no han sido utilizados en una array numérico correlativo con el límite que se ponga por teclado.

Los valores utilizados se generan aleatoriamente, pidiendo por teclado la cantidad de esos números aleatorios que coincidan con el array de números anterior.

Es el problema que propone el OP, pero dando detalles de donde vienen los valores a utilizar y como se obtienen los valores utilizados

Para evaluar uso métodos distintos, por lo que el código podría adaptarse a cualquier circunstancia.

Hay varias formas de realizar el problema, y ésta es la mía, que no es mejor que el resto y que pueda ser peor, pero mis conocimientos llegan hasta aquí

código:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        //pedimos el tamaño del array numérico y recogemo el valor en la variable tamano
        Console.WriteLine("Ponga el tamaño del array numérico correlativo: ");
        int tamano = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        //creamos un array de números con el límite del tamaño llamando al método y recibiendo el array con valores
        int[] arrayNumeros = metodoCrearArrayCorrelativo(tamano);

        //pedimos el números de valores a utilizar del anterior array y recogemos el dato en la variable tamano aleatorio
        Console.WriteLine("Ponga ahora el número de valores a tomar aleatoriamente del array anterior: ");
        int tamanoAleatorios = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        //creamos el array de los números que se usarán llamando al método y recibiendo el array con los valores
        int[] arrayAleatorios = metodoCrearArrayAleatorio(tamano, tamanoAleatorios);

        //llamamos al método donde buscamos los números que no se han utilizado y recibimos el array resultante
        int[] arrayNoCoincidentes = metodoBuscarNoCoincidentes(arrayNumeros, arrayAleatorios);

        //llamamos al método que imprime los valores de los arrays utilizados
        metodoImprimirResultados(arrayNumeros, arrayAleatorios, arrayNoCoincidentes);
    }
    //método que imprime los valores de los arrays que recibe los recibe por parámetro
    private static void metodoImprimirResultados(int[] arrayNumeros, int[] arrayAleatorios, int[] arrayNoCoincidentes)
    {
        //creamos un separación con una línea
        Console.WriteLine("\n---------------------------------------------------");
        //damos detalle del array del que se trata
        Console.WriteLine("Los valores del arrays Correlativo son: ");
        //bucle que recorre el array
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumeros.Length; i++)
        {
            //condicional que pone coma entre cada número excepto detrás del último
            if (i < arrayNumeros.Length - 1)
            {
                //se imprime del valor que corresponde con la variable de la iteración del bucle más una coma
                Console.Write(arrayNumeros[i] + ", ");
            }
            else
            {
                //se imprime del valor que corresponde con la variable de la iteración del bucle
                Console.Write(arrayNumeros[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n---------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Los valores usados del array Correlativo son: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayAleatorios.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j < arrayAleatorios.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(arrayAleatorios[j] + ", ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(arrayAleatorios[j]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n---------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Los valores que NO han sido usados son: ");
        for (int k = 0; k < arrayNoCoincidentes.Length; k++)
        {
            if (k < arrayNoCoincidentes.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(arrayNoCoincidentes[k] + ", ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(arrayNoCoincidentes[k]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n---------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
    //método que busca los valores que no han sido usados que recibe por parámetro el array de números y el de usados
    private static int[] metodoBuscarNoCoincidentes(int[] numeros, int[] usados)
    {
        //se crea un array de no usados con el límete de la resta del array de números menos el array de usados
        int[] arrayC = new int[numeros.Length - usados.Length];

        //bucle que itera en el array de no usados
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayC.Length; i++)
        {
            //bucle que itera en el array de usados
            for (int j = 0; j < usados.Length; j++)
            {
                //bucle que itera en el array de números
                for (int k = 0; k < numeros.Length; k++)
                {
                    //si los valores de iteración correspondientes en cada array es direfente
                    if (usados[j] != numeros[k])
                    {
                        //y si ese valor del array números aún no está contenido en el array de no usados
                        if (!arrayC.Contains(numeros[k]))
                        {
                            //lo agregamos al lugar correspondiente en la iteración de su bucle
                            arrayC[i] = numeros[k];
                        }                       
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
        //ordenamos el array
        Array.Sort(arrayC);
        //lo retornamos
        return arrayC;
    }
    //método que crea y da valores aleatorios al array de números usados que recibe por parámetro los tamaños de los arrays de números y de usados
    private static int[] metodoCrearArrayAleatorio(int tamano, int tamanoA)
    {
        //generamos un nuevo array con el tamaño dado por pantalla
        int[] arrayA = new int[tamanoA];
        //declaramos una variable booelana
        bool correcto;

        //bucle que recorre el array
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.Length; i++)
        {
            //creamos un valor aleatorio comprendido entre los valores del array de números (1 y el tamaño dado por teclado)
            var aleatorio = new Random().Next(1, tamano + 1);  
            //bucle do while que itera mientras no se encuentre un valor aleatorio que no se repita
            do
            {
                //ponemos la variable a true dentro del bucle do while
                correcto = true;
                //bucle que recorre el array
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayA.Length; j++)
                {
                    //si el número generado es igual a cualquiera de los que contiene el array
                    if (aleatorio == arrayA[j])
                    {      
                        //se pone la variable a falso para que continue con la iteración buscando un número número
                        correcto = false;
                        //se genera un nuevo número aleatorio
                        aleatorio = new Random().Next(1, tamano + 1);
                    }
                }
            //si la variable está a false, vuelve a iterar de nuevo
            } while (correcto == false);
            //si la variable está en correcto, se podría suprimir, pues si está en false seguiría en el bucle do while
            if (correcto)
            {
                //agregamos el número al array
                arrayA[i] = aleatorio;
            }
        }
        //ordenamos el array
        Array.Sort(arrayA);
        //retornamos el array
        return arrayA;
    }
    //método que crea un array de números correlativos con el tamaño indicado por teclado
    public static int[] metodoCrearArrayCorrelativo(int tamano)
    {
        //creamos el array con el límete del número recibido por parámetro
        int[] arrayC = new int[tamano];
        //bucle que itera en el array
        for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++)
        {
            //damos valores correlativos al array de la posición de la vairable de la iteración del bucle más 1 para no poner un valor 0
            arrayC[i] = (i + 1);
        }
        //retornamos el array
        return arrayC;
    }
```

Comment: La clase Enumerable en C# tiene el metodo Except() que hace exactamente eso.  Ejemplo aquí https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0

Comment: Jaja, pues ya lo podría haber sabido primero, porque anda que no me ha llevado tiempo confeccionar la solución. indagaré sobre el método que me citas. Muchas gracias por el apunte @Duston, uno que va a remolque y muy poco a poco.